# How to step into native code with disassembling in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, assembly, java-native-interface, reverse-engineering

I am trying to step into(F7) a native function in Android Studio, but it steps over. I want to step into the native function by LLDB, and disassembling the function.
How to step into a native library(so) without native source code(CPP) in Android Studio?